# My website is showing an error related to googlecm.hit.gemius.pl in console

Tags: wordpress, console, adsense

I have a WordPress website, and I use Adsense. However, for a couple of days, I have noticed these errors in the console, and I don't know what they mean.

All of them are related to this URL: https://googlecm.hit.gemius.pl

The errors are saying:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID  

GET googlecm.hit.gemius.pl/googleredir?rid=... net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

I don't know what it is, please clarify this to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. It was not the plugin, but rather an Ad Network on Google Adsense. All I had to do was go into the Google Adsense >> Blocking Controls >> Content >> Ad Networks. Then type in Gemius and disable all ads from their network. The problem goes away and you get to work with Adsense again.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case here. At first I thought my website was hacked or something.

Comment: Gemius clearly abuse DNS records with address 255.255.255.255 which is the root cause for the error. Why Google tolerate such scum is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the best answer, but ...  I noticed my site is doing this too.  It's a pretty simple site, with just a few tools some people use.  If I disable Google's ads, the error goes away.  If I re-enable them, they come back.   I double checked ad content, and they're all legitimate.

The requests aren't being generated by my pages.  They are only generated by Google's ads.

My site is hand coded, not WP or another CMS, so it can't be a hack or anything.  I literally read every line of code related to that page while trying to diagnose it.  It wasn't hard, because there aren't many lines of code. :)

So, to make the error go away, you'll need to turn off Google's ads for a while.  It really isn't necessary though.

The good news is, that error means nothing was sent to the gemius page.  It is simply unreachable right now, for whatever reason.   I guess Google will fix it eventually. I don't care enough to open a trouble ticket with them. I'm just considering it a curiosity and annoyance on my otherwise error free pages.

[screenshot with googlecm.hit.gemius errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olUXn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is related to the plugin Google Ad Inserter. Took me a while to figure out and I'm still trying to clean it up. After removing the plugin a lot of the redirect errors went away and Google was able to index my URL. After going into Chrome developer though I noticed that there was still some redirect errors happening on some resources left behind by Ad Inserter. Once I figure out how to get rid of them I'll post an update. Had a huge impact on my blog though. Almost lost 30% of my page views for the past couple days...